# how to make an api for ionic from two tables(users and posts) in database

Tags: php, laravel-4, ionic-framework, single-page-application, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to make an api (i use laravel 4.2 for backend)for use of the ionic app.
for example:

//I made the following $tourists:

```
                    $tourists = User::where('block','0')
                          ->where('guider', 1)
                           ->where('location', $location)
                           ->orderBy($orderBy, 'desc')
                           ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                           ->get(); 
                 return View::make('frontend.data.touristsData',array('tourists'=>$tourists));
```

// touristsData :

```
    <?php
  echo json_encode($tourists);
```

//used it in my app.js(ionic):

```
.controller('listController', ['$scope','$http','$state','$ionicModal', function($scope, $http, $state,$ionicModal){

    $http.get("./touristsData").success(

         function(data){
            $scope.tourists = data;
......
```

//used in the html

```
<div>{{tourists.username}}: {{tourists.intro}}</div>
```

//the above is for one table

but what if  i have two tables, for example, users table and posts table

//users table (laravel migration)

```
            $table -> increments('id');//id auto_increment
        $table -> string('username',30);
        $table -> string('email',60) -> unique();
        $table -> string('password',64);
        $table -> boolean('admin')->default(0);
        $table -> boolean('block')->default(0);

        $table -> integer('tradeTime');
        $table -> string('nationality', 50);
```

//posts table

```
            $table->increments('id');
        $table -> integer('needHour');


        $table -> string('travelDestination',40);
        $table -> text('intro',300);
        $table -> string('otherWords', 100);
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->softDeletes();   

        $table ->timestamps();
```

//user.php

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';
       protected $guard = array('email', 'password');

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');


    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('Posts');
    }
```

//post.php

```
    <?php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;
class post extends Eloquent{
   use SoftDeletingTrait;
   protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

  protected $fillable = ['needHour', 'travelDestination','intro','otherWords'];


  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
  }
}
```

we can see that the users table and posts table is linked to each other by user_id,
so my question is how we can output the contents of the two table combined ,just  like the above ,which only has one table to output(that is easy)?

what i want to achevie is like the following code:

```
<div>{{tourists.username}} : {{tourists.travelDestination}}</div>
```

Comment: You should really stick with a name convention for models and tables. Your table name is posts and its model is 'Need'. I can't see the namespaces of the models. Are both on the same namespace?

Comment: sorry,just changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this.

**You can use joins**

```
$userWithDestinations = User::where('condition')->join('destination_table', function ($join)
{
   $join->on('user.userID', '=', 'post_table.userID')
})->where('moreConditions')->get()
```

**You can use Laravel Eager Loading** (I strongly recommend this approach for reusable purposes)

Your user model could look like this

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Posts');
    }       
}
```

In order to do something like this:

```
$userWithDestinations = User::where('condition')->with(['posts'])->where('moreConditions')->get();
```

This last code using the eager loading will generate a JSON data like this:

```
[
    {
        userID:1,
        name: Luis,
        posts:
        [
            {
                postID: 1,
                travelDestination: 'Mexico'
            },
            {
                postID: 11,
                travelDestination: 'France'
            },              
        ]
    },
    {
        userID:13,
        name: John,
        posts:
        [
            {
                postID: 14,
                travelDestination: 'Germany'
            },
            {
                postID: 55,
                travelDestination: 'Brazil'
            },              
        ]
    }       
]
```

Since your USER-POSTS is a 1-N relationship, in Angular you could do something like the following code if you want to get only the first post per user.

```
{{tourist.username}} : {{tourist.posts[0].travelDestination}}
```

**Larevel Model Docs**

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

**NOTE**

Your question summary isn't actually about "makie an API", it's more of a Laravel-Model doubt.

Comment: By the way, I am using laravel 4.2, in which I use your answer (eager loading way)but seems not working

Comment: Make sure you created the relationship with the post Model. By the way, I figure that you do have a Model for the "posts" table, right?

Comment: I do have and I will show it in my question. Wait a sec

Comment: Thanks . i make it by using your answer. Really appreciated